# c++ fgets Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, fgets

The full set of code that encompasses the following snippet compiles with out any error. However when I run the executable I receive an error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" when line 401 is executed.

I did some debugging and I know that the "real" file name is getting called in line 397 and I have confirmed that "cur_step_buff" is 4096.

Also, please let me know if more code is needed to help with this issue.

Here is the code:

```
393: FILE *fd;
394: char fd_name[512];
395: strcpy(fd_name,npb_list[freq][app][thread].file_name);
396: fopen( fd_name, "r");
397: cout << "fd_name = " << fd_name << "\n";
398: char cur_step_buff[4096];
399: cout << sizeof(cur_step_buff) << "\n";
400: cout << “location line 400\n”; 
401: fgets (cur_step_buff, sizeof cur_step_buff, fd);
402: int isEnd=0;
403: int last_step=0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that fd/fopen was not getting initialized on line 396

The modified code below allowed my program to run:

Here is the code:

```
393: FILE *fd;
394: char fd_name[512];
395: strcpy(fd_name,npb_list[freq][app][thread].file_name);
396: fd = fopen( fd_name, "r"); // <<- change made to this line
397: cout << "fd_name = " << fd_name << "\n";
398: char cur_step_buff[4096];
399: cout << sizeof(cur_step_buff) << "\n";
400: cout << “location line 400\n”; 
401: fgets (cur_step_buff, sizeof cur_step_buff, fd);
402: int isEnd=0;
403: int last_step=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably intended to assign something to `fd`. Probably the result of `fopen(fd_name, "r");`

Comment: exactly, that's why I vote for this to close. Nothing to offer to future readers.

Comment: should the "fd" at the end of line 401 be "fd_name"?

Comment: I did what I suggested above and now I have a compile error :   error: cannot convert ‘char*’ to ‘FILE* {aka _IO_FILE*}’ for argument ‘3’ to ‘char* fgets(char*, int, FILE*)’

Comment: I was able to get the program to work -please see my answer below